# Summing length of lines of a specific category from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, line, intersection

I have a polygon layer of ski resorts call `skiResorts`.  I have a liner layer of pistes called `pistes`.  The pistes layer has 2 several attributes and include `aa_piste_length` and `aa_piste_difficulty`.  `aa_piste_difficulty` includes 3 categories, namely, `beginner`, `intermediate` and `advanced`.

In the `skiResorts` layer, I would like to make 3 new calculated fields, namely, `beginner_length`, `intermediate_length` and `advanced_length` which sums the value of `aa_piste_length`.  For example, `beginner_length` in the `skiResorts` layer would be the sum of all `aa_piste_difficulty` that equals `beginner` and is within that particular `skiReport` polygon.

I am very confused as to how to do this.  Do I need to make a one to many relationship between skiResorts and pistes?  Can I just use aggregate in the Field Calculator to do this?

I have tried below but still have questions how to complete it.

```
aggregate(layer:= 'pistes',
      aggregate:= 'sum',
      expression:= ?? what does here?? ,
      filter:= ?? how to say where piste_difficulty = beginner ??
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First solution: use `overlay_intersects()`

I recommend using [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) function ([available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core)). It is easier to handle when it involves (as here) spatial relationship (take into consideration only *overlapping* pistes).

Use the follwong expression. You get an array of all `aa_piste_length` values from layer `pistes`, filtered by the value defined at the end of line 5. Use [`array_sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-sum) to get the sum:

```
array_sum(
    overlay_intersects (
        'pistes',
        aa_piste_length,
        filter:=aa_piste_difficulty='beginner'
    )
)
```

---

### Second solution: use `aggregate()`

Just for curiosity since you asked how to use `aggregate()` function. The expression argument is simply the field name whose values you want to sum. The filter, howver, has to take into consideration intersection features only as well as category values. The expression looks like this:

```
aggregate(
    layer:= 'pistes',
    aggregate:= 'sum',
    expression:= "aa_piste_length",
    filter:=intersects (geometry(@parent), $geometry) and "aa_piste_difficulty"='beginner' 
)
```

---

**Edit**

See [help of the `aggregate()` function](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) how the optional filter expression to limit the features used for calculating the aggregate works:

> Fields and geometry are from the features on the joined layer. The
> source feature can be accessed with the variable `@parent`.

So here, we calculate the intersection of the geometry of the current (=joined) layer - [`$geometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry) - with the [geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id27) of the source feature - `geometry (@parent)`

*Remark: in QGIS versions 3.28 and later, `$geometry` is replaced by `@geometry`*.

Comment: I used the aggregate() function, however, I do not quite understand how geometry(@parent),$geometry) works.  Thank you for the multiple solutions!

Comment: See updated answer/Edit at the bottom of the answer for this.